# Is this variable "fixed" for the whole project?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, static

I'm in a .NET 4.0 WebForms, and in a class I have this variable:

```
public static readonly string twitter_aggrega_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
public static readonly string twitter_aggrega_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

since I can't set them as `const`, I'd like to know if they can "change" in some ways during the process. How they are managed by .NET? Is it possible access to it at some point of the application, and than after some "ticks" later get two different values?

I need them the same for the whole process, but different every time the process start. Hope it is clear what I'd like to achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` variables are alive for the life of the AppDomain. As long as your application remains open, your `static readonly` variables will never change.. unless you change them in a *static* constructor.

Comment: But when they are built? When the process starts? Or every time I call them are "calculated"?

Comment: They are initialized at an undetermined time. `static` initialization is up to the implementation. However, it is guaranteed that they are initialized before their first use in an application.

Comment: Ok, so calling those variables at time X and to X+1 means I'll always get the same value, even if they are fixed to the Ticks time. What I need ;)

Comment: Correct. They aren't recalculated every time. Only once.. but the time at which that once occurs is undetermined.